# Отправка фото с Андроид на сервер и переправка его опрделенному пользователю

Tags: xml, android, php, java

Добрый день!
Я сделал небольшой чат в котором есть возможность переписки между Андроид девайсами.
Теперь хочу добавить возможность отправки изображений, например с камеры. Как сделать фото, преобразовать его в битмап, а его в свою очередь в Base64 я разобрался!

Теперь вопрос как его отправить на сервер, там преобразовать его обратно в .png, сложить в базу и далее отправить в xml ссылку на это изображение пользователю которому она предназначена!

Ниже функция которая отвечает за отправку простого сообщения, я думаю там необходимо внести немного изменений но каких не доходит, в php я хуже новичка!

```
case "sendMessage":
if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
    {   
    if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
    {
         $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
         $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

         $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";

                if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                {
                    while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                    {
                        $uto = $rowto->Id;
                    }
                    $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";

                            error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                        if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                        {
                                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                        }               
                        else {
                                $out = FAILED;
                        }                       
                    $resultto = NULL;
                }

    $sqlto = NULL;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        $out = FAILED;
    }   
break;
```

Кусочек формирования XML:

```
if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                        {
                        while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                            {
                            $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                            $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                            $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                            }
                        }
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот пара решенных вопросов с примерами. В частности как отправить файл с андроида и как получить файл в php:

Клиентская часть:

- [Как отправить используя MultipartEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829760/android-how-to-upload-video-image-to-php-server)
- [Для MultipartEntity вот неплохой пример использования](http://www.framesocket.com/for-developers/examples/android/)
- [Или такой](https://gist.github.com/Kieranties/2225346)

Серверная часть:

- [Вот, как получить в php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380827/php-for-receiving-image-and-text-from-multipartentity)

Comment: @Gleb Kuznetsov это не ответ, а что-то типа [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/) какой-то

Comment: @Barmaley полностью с Вами согласен! Не понимаю неужели люди думают что мне было легче оставить здесь вопрос на который я потратил 10 минут, нежели за 10 секунд набрать запрос в гугле?